# Why does division parallelize but not continued fractions and is there an analog of multiplication to continued fractions?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, computational-complexity, computer-science, fourier-transform, continued-fractions

All the basic arithmetic operations $\times,+,/,-$ can be parallelized. However continued fraction representation of a rational number is not parallelized. The process of Euclid's algorithm looks similar to division. In division we keep the divisor same and repeat by adding $0$s after the decimal. In Euclid's algorithm we change the divisor with remainder and dividend with divisor and repeat. Division has a period that could be very long (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377683/length-of-period-of-decimal-expansion-of-a-fraction) while continued fraction terminates in logarithmic steps. Despite this division is in $NC$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_(complexity)#Problems_in_NC) while the short hand notation is difficult to parallelize.

> 1. Is there a mathematical reason why this should be the case? I am not asking this would show $GCD$ is in $NC$ as an obstacle.

Secondly given $p,q$ coprimes we can form $r=\frac pq$ where $r\in\mathbb R$ is a decimal representation of $\frac pq$. Now given $r$ and $q$ we can find $p$ by multiplication.

> 2. Is there a similar operation for $c$ the continued fraction representation of $\frac pq$ that is
>
> a. properly defined directly
>
> b. properly defined in $NC$
>
> and gives $p$ from $c$ and $q$?

Comment: "the continued fraction representation of $q$..." Do you mean, the continued fraction representation of $p/q$? And what does "properly defined directly" mean?

Comment: $c=[c_1,\dots,c_n]$ where $\frac pq=c_1+\frac1{c_2+\frac1{\dots+\frac1{c_n}}}$ holds.

Comment: I don't think that engages with my questions. It really looks like $c$ is the representation of $p/q$; are you sure you want to write that, no, it's the representation of $q$?

Comment: I mean we can lift it back to $r$ and get $p$ from $rq$ and can we avoid this indirect route? Is there a direct operation $c\diamond q=p$ where $\diamond$ is in $NC$?

Comment: If it is meaningless I will remove. It seems pointless to lift it to $r$ which can be exponentially long and get $p$. Perhaps there is a way to do this in polynomial space without lifting. Of course we could have stopped at $\frac pq$ itself instead of going to $r$ but even that is not in $NC$.

Comment: There is a relevant paper by Sedjelmaci, The Integer Greatest Common Divisor is NC (2007). In the conclusion section they mention that this implies that modular inversion is also in NC. So I'm guessing running a full extended Euclidean algorithm is also in NC, which would mean continued fractions are there too. Check out the paper and see if it gives you a direction.

Comment: As for the second question, I'm not familiar with the particulars of the NC class, but given `c` you can distribute the multiplication of the matrices $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a_i \\ & 1 \end{pmatrix}$: use $n/2$ processors to multiply consecutive pairs, then $n/4$ processors to multiple consecutive pairs from the previous stage... until you've multiplied them all. There are $O(\log{n})$ stages, and this produces the $p$ (and $q$, even though you had it as input). Is this algorithm in NC? What I'm worried about is that the sizes of the integers in the matrices grow until it they reach $n$-bits...

Comment: You can do the above mod different primes in order to keep the integer sizes bounded, so that computing $p \pmod{r}$ is definitely in NC. Then, you need $O(n)$ different $r$'s. So distribute over about $O(n^2)$ processors, which is allowed. Since modular inversion is in NC, I'm sure that CRT is in NC. And this should answer your second question positively.